# Need to return string but only getting a int with random number generator

Tags: java, random, generator

Can't figure out why my code will only return a Int when I need a String and help would be great. code below . I tried declaring variable as String with no luck.

I want to return 3 random strings:  cherry, grape, bell or x

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class slot {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String answer = "y";
        int cherry;
        int grape;
        int bell;
        int x;



        Random generator = new Random(); // random generator
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in); // scanner class

        System.out.println("Would you like to play the slot machine?(y/n): ");
        answer = scan.nextLine();

        while(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {
             cherry = generator.nextInt(5); // generates a random number
            grape = generator.nextInt(5);
            bell = generator.nextInt(5);

            System.out.println("The three numbers of the slot machine are: " + cherry +grape +bell);

            if(cherry == grape && grape == bell)
               {
                System.out.println("JACKPOT! All three of the same");
               }

            if(cherry == grape || cherry == bell || grape == bell )
               {
                System.out.println("Close, you got two of the same!!");
               }
            else
               {
                System.out.println("Not a winner");
               }

            System.out.print("Try again?(y/n): ");
            answer = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println();
        }


        System.out.println("Bye!!");

    }

}
```

Comment: The method is `void` which means that it does not return anything at all. Where exactly are you trying to "return" a string?

Comment: Could you describe the problem a bit more precisely? Where is something returned as an int?

Comment: It's summer holiday time now, isn't it? :)

Comment: Other than your problem, you should also check you ifs, the first falls through to the second which is not what you want. Also, your code makes no sense to a reader - how can a grape equal a cherry? You probably should rename grape to be 'wheel1', cherry to 'wheel2' etc - at least it will read better!

Comment: "NO" not homework, thanks for all the great help folks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would formulate it like this:

```
// The different results each "wheel" / "column" on the slot machine.
String[] results = { "cherry", "bell", "grape", "x" };

// Create a random result for each wheel.
String wheel1 = results[generator.nextInt(results.length)];
String wheel2 = results[generator.nextInt(results.length)];
String wheel3 = results[generator.nextInt(results.length)];
```

and then continue with your `if` statements. (But do `else if` for the second and third statement).

```
if (wheel1 == wheel2 && wheel2 == wheel3) {
    // jackpot
} else if (wheel1 == wheel2 || wheel2 == wheel3 || wheel1 == wheel3) {
    // two equal
} else {
    // all three different.
}
```

If you want to go deeper into the language, I recommend you to look into `enum`s.

(Note that comparing strings using `==` is in 9 cases out of 10 a bad idea. Here however, we don't need to bother with comparing string *content* but can get away by comparing *reference values*.)

Answer (score 1):

Declaring strings as ints does not make them integer values. What you need to do is make an array which contains the words you're using. Then generate a random int value which is within the scope of the array.

Then you'll pick the word from the array which is in the location specified by the random int you have.

EDIT: I'm sorry, I didn't read your whole question. Could you tell us what is getting printed?

Answer (score 1):

your are printing the values of your `int`s. Try this: You generate a number and depending on this number you choose your String.

```
Random generator = new Random();
    int a = generator.nextInt(5); 
    int b = generator.nextInt(5);  
    int c = generator.nextInt(5); 

    String roll1 = null;
    switch(b){
    case 1: roll1 = "cherry";
            break;
    case 2: roll1 = "grape";
            break;
    case 3: roll1 = "bell";
            break;
    default: roll1 = "xxx";
             break;
    }
    //repeat for b and c with roll2 and roll3
    System.out.println(roll1);
```